# How to get more detailed error info in EWS SOAP response?

Tags: delphi, soap, exchangewebservices, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm posting SOAP calls to Exchange webservices (using Delphi and the IpWorks TipwHTTP component) and *some* of these return with internal server errors (some CreateItem and UpdateItem SOAP actions), but no more info than that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<s:Fault>
<faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">a:ErrorInternalServerError</faultcode>
<faultstring xml:lang="en-US">An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.</faultstring>
<detail>
<e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorInternalServerError</e:ResponseCode>
<e:Message xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.</e:Message>
</detail>
</s:Fault>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

With the EWS Managed API there is such a thing as [tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-trace-requests-responses-to-troubleshoot-ews-managed-api-applications), but I'm not using that API.
[Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/81346918-f2bb-4220-ab5a-7eaf9ee47aa0/ews-office-365-an-internal-server-error-occurred-the-operation-failed?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment) is an example of a user who got more detailed error information using that:

```
<m:ResponseMessages>
  <m:FindItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
    <m:MessageText>An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.</m:MessageText>
    <m:ResponseCode>ErrorInternalServerError</m:ResponseCode>
    <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
    <m:MessageXml>
      <t:Value Name="InnerErrorMessageText">Too many concurrent connections opened.</t:Value>
      <t:Value Name="InnerErrorResponseCode">ErrorTooManyObjectsOpened</t:Value>
      <t:Value Name="InnerErrorDescriptiveLinkKey">0</t:Value>
    </m:MessageXml>
  </m:FindItemResponseMessage>
</m:ResponseMessages>
```

Is there something I can add to the SOAP request, or maybe the HTTP headers, that gives me that additional error information?

Full example of a failing call:

----Request----

```
POST /ews/exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: webmail.timetellbv.nl
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVN[snip]AAAA=
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: IPWorks HTTP Component - www.nsoftware.com
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/UpdateItem"
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 6485



<soapenv:Envelope
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:typ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
  xmlns:mes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
<soapenv:Header>
  <typ:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>
  <typ:MailboxCulture>en-US</typ:MailboxCulture>
  <typ:TimeZoneContext>
     <typ:TimeZoneDefinition Id="W. Europe Standard Time"/>
  </typ:TimeZoneContext>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<mes:UpdateItem ConflictResolution="AlwaysOverwrite" SendMeetingInvitationsOrCancellations="SendToNone">
   <mes:ItemChanges>
      <typ:ItemChange>
         <typ:ItemId Id="AAMkADQz[snip]wAAA=" ChangeKey="DwAAA[snip]nxYa" />
         <typ:Updates>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                 <typ:Subject>Voorbereiden op Fokkema (10-3)</typ:Subject>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Sensitivity"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                 <typ:Sensitivity>Normal</typ:Sensitivity>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Categories"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                  <typ:Categories>
                     <typ:String>TimeTell</typ:String>
                  </typ:Categories>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Body"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                 <typ:Body BodyType="Text">Export projectgegevens van budget naar planningsmodule.</typ:Body>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:Location"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                 <typ:Location></typ:Location>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:IsAllDayEvent"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                 <typ:IsAllDayEvent>false</typ:IsAllDayEvent>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:Start"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                 <typ:Start>2020-03-04T13:00:00.000+01:00</typ:Start>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:End"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                 <typ:End>2020-03-04T15:00:00.000+01:00</typ:End>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:LegacyFreeBusyStatus"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                 <typ:LegacyFreeBusyStatus>Busy</typ:LegacyFreeBusyStatus>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:MeetingTimeZone"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                  <typ:MeetingTimeZone TimeZoneName="W. Europe Standard Time"/>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="TimeTellID" PropertyType="Integer"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                  <typ:ExtendedProperty>
                     <typ:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="TimeTellID" PropertyType="Integer"/>
                     <typ:Value>1707908</typ:Value>
                  </typ:ExtendedProperty>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="TimeTellSyncTime" PropertyType="SystemTime"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                  <typ:ExtendedProperty>
                     <typ:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="TimeTellSyncTime" PropertyType="SystemTime"/>
                     <typ:Value>2020-03-03T10:09:41.949+01:00</typ:Value>
                  </typ:ExtendedProperty>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="TimeTellSyncVer" PropertyType="Integer"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                  <typ:ExtendedProperty>
                     <typ:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="TimeTellSyncVer" PropertyType="Integer"/>
                     <typ:Value>90100</typ:Value>
                  </typ:ExtendedProperty>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="TimeTellSyncID" PropertyType="String"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                  <typ:ExtendedProperty>
                     <typ:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="TimeTellSyncID" PropertyType="String"/>
                     <typ:Value>00000[snip]000</typ:Value>
                  </typ:ExtendedProperty>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
         </typ:Updates>
      </typ:ItemChange>
   </mes:ItemChanges>
</mes:UpdateItem>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

----Response----

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
request-id: 679f24c4-547e-4728-a102-049708a78b3a
X-CalculatedBETarget: ttexchange2016.timetellbv.nl
X-DiagInfo: TTEXCHANGE2016
X-BEServer: TTEXCHANGE2016
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=4b2979acfda04a04896f69c7e3d6d60d; expires=Wed, 03-Mar-2021 09:07:41 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-BackEndCookie=S-1-5-21-856652257-446748123-1738634499-1192=u56Lnp[snip]Bzw==; expires=Thu, 02-Apr-2020 09:07:41 GMT; path=/ews; secure; HttpOnly
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-FEServer: TTEXCHANGE2016
Date: Tue, 03 Mar 2020 09:07:41 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<s:Fault>
<faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">a:ErrorInternalServerError</faultcode>
<faultstring xml:lang="en-US">An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.</faultstring>
<detail>
<e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorInternalServerError</e:ResponseCode>
<e:Message xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.</e:Message>
</detail>
</s:Fault>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

(I formatted that last XML part). As you can see there is no more error info than the 'internal error'.

**Added** based on the discussion in the comments:

- I rewrote a SOAP request in a test app to use a RequestServerVersion of 'Exchange2010', 'Exchange2013' or 'Exchange2016' but this gave no additional info in the XML response.
- There was nothing in the Exchange logs. Setting more detailed logging in Exchange did not change that.

Comment: Do you have access to the EWS logs?

Comment: On a side note, what exchange version are you targeting? (2007 is old ;) )

Comment: @whosrdaddy 1. (Logs) I can ask an admin. But that won't help if this happens with a client 2. (Version) That's the lowest common denominator in the outgoing calls. Yes, we still support that. Current tests are against Exchange2016 or online. If something is available in later versions but not in 2007 we may change the RequestServerVersion.

Comment: I guess this is all you will get via SOAP. I've done a bit of EWS development myself, but I used the managed C# API as it is super straightforward.

Comment: Tracing in the Managed API just captures the soap request and response it doesn't add anything into the request it self. I would suggest you do change RequestServerVersion to match the server your using (its best practice and easy you get version in every response anyway) and from memory InnerErrorMessageText was added in later versions of Exchange so may only be returned for specific schema versions and above.

Comment: @GlenScales I tried doing that (set outgoing RequestServerVersion in subsequent calls with the one detected in the first call) but that gives compatibility errors like *The property is deprecated for this version of Exchange. Either use StartTimeZone or EndTimeZone, or both, for this version or use MeetingTimeZone with an earlier version of Exchange in the RequestServerVersion SOAP header.* I would have to go over every call and construct them so that they are fit for all detected versions (or at least a number of versions).

Comment: @GlenScales Do you know which Exchange version introduced *InnerErrorMessageText*? It may be worth doing the rewrite for that as minimum version.

Comment: 2010 AFAIK, I guess the question is if the problem is reproducible does using the updated TimeZone properties and schema fix the issue ? if so it sounds like the legacy requests your making aren't being handled by the server for the particular timezones which could be bug in particular version of Exchange.

Comment: @GlenScales There is no bug there. If I request version 2007_SP1 I need to construct some calls differently than when using later versions. That is documented behavior and the error message is as expected.