# Parameter name 'key' cannot be null for EWS SOAP UpdateItem call

Tags: soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm getting an internal server error for `Parameter name: key` when trying to update a calendar appointment.
It 'cannot be null'. What can this mean? There is no parameter 'key'. Is `&#xD` the value being reported on?
When browsing around on SO for *Parameter name 'key' cannot be null* I get the idea it could be a programming error in Exchange Server itself.

`select @@version` gives:
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU2) (KB4013106) - 13.0.4422.0 (X64) 
    Mar  6 2017 14:18:16 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

This is the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="20" MajorBuildNumber="2814" MinorBuildNumber="22" Version="V2018_01_08" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <m:UpdateItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <m:ResponseMessages>
        <m:UpdateItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
          <m:MessageText>An internal server error occurred. The operation failed., Value cannot be null.&#xD;
          Parameter name: key</m:MessageText>
          <m:ResponseCode>ErrorInternalServerError</m:ResponseCode>
          <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
          <m:Items/>
        </m:UpdateItemResponseMessage>
      </m:ResponseMessages>
    </m:UpdateItemResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

to this request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:typ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
  xmlns:mes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
<soapenv:Header>
  <typ:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010"/>
  <typ:MailboxCulture>en-US</typ:MailboxCulture>
  <typ:TimeZoneContext>
     <typ:TimeZoneDefinition Id="W. Europe Standard Time"/>
  </typ:TimeZoneContext>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<mes:UpdateItem ConflictResolution="AlwaysOverwrite" SendMeetingInvitationsOrCancellations="SendToNone">
   <mes:ItemChanges>
      <typ:ItemChange>
         <typ:ItemId Id="AQMkAGMz[snip]AAAA==" ChangeKey="DwAA[snip]JuniP+" />
         <typ:Updates>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                 <typ:Subject>Gewijzigde afspraak? Ik denk het wel</typ:Subject>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Sensitivity"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                 <typ:Sensitivity>Normal</typ:Sensitivity>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Categories"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                  <typ:Categories>
                     <typ:String>TimeTell</typ:String>
                  </typ:Categories>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Body"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                 <typ:Body BodyType="Text">Aangemaakt door Wendy</typ:Body>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:Location"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                 <typ:Location></typ:Location>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:IsAllDayEvent"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                 <typ:IsAllDayEvent>false</typ:IsAllDayEvent>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:Start"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                 <typ:Start>2020-03-31T16:56:27.929+02:00</typ:Start>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:End"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                 <typ:End>2020-03-31T17:56:27.929+02:00</typ:End>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:LegacyFreeBusyStatus"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                 <typ:LegacyFreeBusyStatus>Busy</typ:LegacyFreeBusyStatus>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:StartTimeZone"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                  <typ:StartTimeZone TimeZoneName="W. Europe Standard Time"/>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:EndTimeZone"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                  <typ:EndTimeZone TimeZoneName="W. Europe Standard Time"/>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
         </typ:Updates>
      </typ:ItemChange>
   </mes:ItemChanges>
</mes:UpdateItem>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, this was really unpredictable.

I had replaced the `THTTPReqResp` components, with `TipwHTTP` from nSoftware's [IPWorks](https://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/). This uses all ordinary String types.

**But the data sent to EWS needs to be UTF-8**

After all we say `ContentType := 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'`<sup>*</sup>.
After the conversion my code still reads:

```
lHTTP.PostData := FSoapRequest;   // A string type
```

but it should be:

```
lHTTP.PostDataB := BytesOf(UTF8Encode(FSoapRequest));   // UTF8Encode returns a UTF-8 encoded RawByteString with a code page of CP_UTF8 (65001) assigned to it.
```

I found this out by carefully looking at the SOAP calls that failed. They contained things like the Word 'Left single quotation mark' (U-2018, people just copy/paste Word texts in to email), or even the simple diacritics like é and ü, that caused these errors.

<sup>* Yes, the 'utf-8' without quotes, because that's what Exchange Webservices wants</sup>

Notes:

- This is pretty specific, so I thought about just deleting the question, but the situation where EWS gives no more info than 'Internal server error' might occur for others too. Good to leave this as a pointer for investigation.
- The limited error information made me ask the question [How to get more detailed error info in EWS SOAP response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60505086/how-to-get-more-detailed-error-info-in-ews-soap-response)